# IIS: Url Redirect not working when using Relative URL

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, https, webserver

So I'm pretty new to IIS. My problem is that I have set up a URL Rewrite rule to redirect http requests to https and ticket the SSL required box, but it only works when the request URL is `http://site.domain.com`.

When entering `site.domain.com`, it sends the user to the 403 page instead of redirecting to https.

Here is the rule I'm using:

```
<rule name="HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Any advice?

Comment: There is no problem with your url rewrite, please try to clear your browser's cache and try again, you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. The Browser cache was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The Rewrite Rule was fine, the Problem was that the Browser I was using still had the Website cached from before the Redirect was set up. Clearing the cache solved the problem.